# How To Reload Data UITableView using UISegmentedControl in swift

Tags: swift

I am creating a segmentcontrol screen than select specific indexpath and  change data from my tableview. I am using Alamofire to parse the son data.

**Here I created my Struct:**

```
struct jsonstruct {
    var name:String
    var description:String
    var hero_image_url:String
    var date:String
}
```

**There is my code to use `Alamofire`:**
         ....Create First Function.....

```
func ShowData () 
    Alamofire.request("http://soleparadise.com/api/v1/customer/search", method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
        switch(response.result) {

        case .success(_):
            print(response.result.value as Any)
            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] else {return}                   
            guard let data = json["data"] as? [[String:Any]] else { return }       
            print("Response \(data)")
            for item in data {
                let name = item["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let description = item["description"] as? String ?? ""
                let hero_image_url = item["hero_image_url"] as? String ?? ""
                let Date = item["release_date"] as? String ?? ""
                self.jsonData.append(jsonstruct(name: name, description: description, hero_image_url: hero_image_url, date:Date ))                     

                 print(self.jsonData)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async  {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

**There is my second Function:**

```
func NewArriving() {

    let param:[String:Any] = ["new_arriving":"1"] 
    Alamofire.request("http://soleparadise.com/api/v1/customer/search", method:.post, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {

        case .success(_):
            print(response.result.value as Any)
            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] else{ return}
            guard let data = json["data"] as? [[String:Any]] else { return}
            print("Response \(data)")
            for item in data {
                let name = item["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let description = item["description"] as? String ?? ""
                let hero_image_url = item["hero_image_url"] as? String ?? ""
                let Date = item["release_date"] as? String ?? ""
                self.jsonData.append(jsonstruct(name: name, description: description, 
                hero_image_url: hero_image_url, date:Date )) 
                print(self.jsonData)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break
        }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        DispatchQueue.main.async  {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }         
}
```

[image]

There is my `TableviewCell`:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return jsonData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }  

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
            "TableViewCell", for: indexPath)as! TableViewCell
        cell.name.text = jsonData[indexPath.row].name
        cell.descriptions.text = jsonData[indexPath.row].description
        cell.date.text = jsonData[indexPath.row].date
        cell.hero_image_url.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:jsonData[indexPath.row].hero_image_url ), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: " ")
        return cell

    }
}
```

**There is my `segmntAction`:**

```
@IBAction func valueChange(_sender:UISegmentedControl) {

    switch Segment.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0
        tableView.reloadData()
        break
    case 1:
        NewArriving()
        tableView.reloadData()
        break
    default: 
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the error? Or the problem?

Comment: My data not change tableview on select 1 indexpath segment

Comment: I want to select  "PAST" Segment button change to data on tableview...             PAST button:-  API "NEW ARRIVAL":"1" URL:- http://soleparadise.com/api/v1/customer/search

Comment: I don't understand what i am doing wrong in my code. Please help me?

Comment: Hi @NiluSahani. Have you confirm that you code NewArriving() works ? Do you have any prints from the action segmentedControl == 1 ?

Comment: my data not change tableview on select 'indexpath 1'

Comment: ;upcoming' and 'past' both are select segment and found same data in output screen why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the appropriate data in **both** cases and there must be a space character between `_` and `sender`

```
@IBAction func valueChange(_ sender : UISegmentedControl) {

    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex { // use the `sender` parameter rather than the outlet reference
    case 0: ShowData()
    case 1: NewArriving()
    default: 
        break
    }
}
```

The `break` statements within `case` are pointless in Swift and the tableview is reloaded in the completion handlers of the network requests.

And you should conform to the naming convention that function and variable names start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all jsonData then call New API, then reload tableview.